# How to keep mouse keys around

Tags: linux, mouse, keypad

My platform is Linux, and there is a shortcut `Alt + Left Shift + Num Lock` to enable mouse keys TEMPORARILY. They say this feature is provided by X server, so it can be used on all desktop environments based on X. The problem is that the effect doesn't last long. The keypad will switch back to normal keypad automatically, and cannot be used to emulate a mouse. Therefore, whenever I want to move the cursor, the result may become scrolling to the bottom of the current document, which is annoying. Is there any way to prevent X from switching the keypad back to its original keypad function automatically? Thanks.